# Automatic Email from google docs based on vaule in spreadsheet

Tags: email, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a `google spreadsheet`.  When the value in `cell D2 = 5`, I want to automatically send an email to a given address.

Could you help me with the code for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script editor in the google spreadsheets ->  tools -> script editor.

here you can use some similar code in your script:

MailApp.sendEmail(useremail, subject , null,{htmlBody:"Dear"+" "+[i]+newline+" Kindly check your "})

where useremail: is a variable which contains a string email, and so on as you can probably get from the names of the variables.

Comment: for checking out the documentation about the mailapp function available in the scripts check this link :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app